# Link_to in Rails. Link to displayed customized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I have an application, that takes a path of a file from the database and renders it to html and displays. The controller, view and routes look like the following:

`project/index.html.erb`

```
<p><%= link_to project.title,{:controller => "markdowns" , :action => 'view',       :github_link=>project.github_link},:target=>"_blank"%></p>
```

`markdown_controller`

```
class MarkdownsController < ApplicationController
  def view
    @markdown=MarkdownsHelper.markdown path
  end

  def path
    File.open(Rails.public_path.to_s+params[:github_link].to_s, "rb").read
  end
end
```

MarkdownsHelper.markdown method in the above controller renders the .md.

`markdown/view`

```
<%=raw @markdown %>
```

`routes`

```
resources :projects
match '/GitRepos/'=>'markdowns#view'
```

### **The problem:**

The link that is being displayed after clicking on the title in the prokects/index is **localhost:3000/GitRepos?github_link=%2FGitRepos%2Fbootstrap%2FREADME.md**

But I want the link to be displayed as **localhost:3000/GitRepos/bootstrap/Readme.md**

where bootstrap is Project.title and Readme.md is the file that is being read. Also, my Project database has a github_link attribute which stores **GitRepos/bootstrap/Readme.md**

### Model

The link will change according to the project.
The Project model has these attributes-> title and github_link.
So there are many projects and github_link stores the path addresses of Readme.md file of each project located in the local system.

## My Approach

Here is the solution which I have, with my minimal knowledge in Ruby on Rails. Please let me know if can improve on this.

`project/index.html.erb`

```
    <p><%= link_to project.title,{:controller => "markdowns" , :action => 'view',:title=>project.git_name,:id=>project.git_file},:target=>"_blank" %></p>
```

`routes`

```
    match 'GitRepos/:title/:id' =>'markdowns#view'
```

Comment: Is this link constant or will it change ? If yes than which part of the url?

Comment: I just edited the question. Check in the heading Model . Thanks :)

Comment: try to have the link as: `match  '/GitRepos'=>'GitRepos/bootstrap/Readme.md'`

Comment: It doesn't work that way.
It will look for a controller that is being matched to, in this case 'GitRepos/bootstrap/Readme.md'

Where as GitRepos/bootstrap/Readme.md is a path address on the local computer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
match '/GitRepos/:github_link'=>'markdowns#view'
```

Comment: That does not go to Markdown controller. It directly goes to local computer location.